# Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor. Mvc layered architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, dependencies, dbcontext

I am trying to make layered architecture with asp.net mvc ı build all layer business entity  data access i made dependency injection with autofac but if ı try to run my web page ı seen this error[image]

this is my dependency injection class

```cs
builder.RegisterType<DepartmentManager>().As<IDepartmentService>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<EfDepartmentDal>().As<IDepartmentDal>().SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<PersonelManager>().As<IPersonelService>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<EfPersonelDal>().As<IPersonelDal>().SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<HttpContextAccessor>().As<IHttpContextAccessor>();

var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

builder
    .RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .EnableInterfaceInterceptors(
        new ProxyGenerationOptions()
        {
            Selector = new AspectInterceptorSelector()
        }
    )
    .SingleInstance();
```

this is controller

```cs
public class DepartmentController : Controller
{
    private IDepartmentService _departmentService;
        
    public DepartmentController(IDepartmentService departmentService)
    {
        _departmentService = departmentService;
    }

    // GET: Department
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = _departmentService.GetAll();

        if (result.Success)
        {
            return (IActionResult)View(result);
        }

        return (IActionResult)HttpNotFound();
    }
}
```

data context

```cs
public partial class TestContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Personel> Personels { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the controllers as services so that the DI framework will inject the ctor parameters.

In your `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method you have to call the `AddControllersAsServices()` extension method on an `IMvcBuilder` instance.

In your `Startup.cs` file there should be something like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    /// For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services">The container of the services.</param>
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddControllers() // <-- this will return an instance of IMvcBuilder
            .AddControllersAsServices(); // <-- this method call is required.
    }
}
```

If you have an MVC application then you may call the `services.AddMvc()` extension method instead of `services.AddControllers()` to get an `IMvcBuilder` instance.

**UPDATE #1**

Please check my example solution [here](https://github.com/gcsizmadia/EgonsoftHU.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Autofac/tree/main/examples).

You can find two example projects there:

- for [ASP.NET WebApi 2 (.NET Framework 4.8)](https://github.com/gcsizmadia/EgonsoftHU.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Autofac/tree/main/examples/Company.Product.NetFx.WebApi)
- for [ASP.NET Core (.NET 6)](https://github.com/gcsizmadia/EgonsoftHU.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Autofac/tree/main/examples/Company.Product.NetCore.WebApi)

You may also check Autofac documentation:

- [ASP.NET MVC](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html)
- [ASP.NET Core](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html)

Comment: ı tried it but didnt work for me ı dont have Startup.cs file in my app folders i only have global.asax https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/790321261586415696/958793601192693810/unknown.png

Comment: @KadirKaya13, based on your linked image it seems you use ASP.NET MVC with .NET Framework. I updated my answer with links to my example codes and also the related Autofac documentation. The point is that you need to call [`builder.RegisterControllers(...);`](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#quick-start).